# Using a EF 5 project dll with Web project using EF6

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Good afternoon,

I know this has been asked before ([Using a entity framework 5 project dll with Web project using EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499170/using-a-entity-framework-5-project-dll-with-web-project-using-ef6)), but I can't find any answers (and haven't got enough reputation to add a comment to the existing question...)

So here is my question - I have some projects (UI and DLLs) using Entity Framework 5, and I have started a new project using Entity Framework 6. When I reference a DLL based on EF5, I get errors because the DLL is using a different version of the Entity Framework.

Is there a way to make it work? or is having all my projects on the same EF version the only way?

Cheers
C